# API call error: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 5000ms (and no fallback has been configured)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

We are using two service which are completely written in **Spring WebFlux** and while invoking/calling from service **A** to service **B**, we are seeing below error and we are unable to debug further and hard to nail down to what could be ideal root cause for this.

> API call error: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 5000ms (and no fallback has been configured)

```
public Mono<UserSubscription> getUserPrefs(String userId) {
    return client.get().uri(getUserPrefsApiPath, userId)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(userPrefsAPITimeout))
            .doOnError(ex -> logError(userId, ex))
            .map(resp-> {
                UserSubscription us = parseUserOrAppPreferenceData(resp, userId);
                logger.info("Retrieved from User Preference API: "+us);
                return  us;
            })
            .onErrorResume(e->{
                logger.error("Cannot retrieve user preferences - API call error: "+e.getMessage(), e);
                return Mono.just(new UserSubscription(userId,null, new ArrayList<>()));
            });
}
```

Comment: What type of API call is this? Are you doing large data transfer in this API call.

Comment: See if this helps https://kalpads.medium.com/configuring-timeouts-in-spring-reactive-webclient-4bc5faf56411

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen - Please find the below snippet

Comment: @DineshN i'm not sure you added a code snippet. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen Apologies may bad - I have just added on the question - Only thing I have observed here is this is not a real TCP timeout and I see its more off a signal timeout that surfaces when there is no subscribeon from consumer or might be the case service is unable to fork a thread in the given duration within the service

Comment: what is the value of `userPrefsAPITimeout`? Is it 5s?

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing the `.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(<secondsHere>))` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `onErrorReturn()`

```
public Mono<UserSubscription> getUserPrefs(String userId) {
    return client.get().uri(getUserPrefsApiPath, userId)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(userPrefsAPITimeout))
            .onErrorReturn(//TODO//);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that server B failed to respond to service A within 5000ms.
It was probably important for you that the response time should be done within a limited period of time, otherwise you can remove the timeout.
But I suggest instead of clearing the timeout, print an error message and return a default value.

```
.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(userPrefsAPITimeout))
.onErrorResume(e -> {
      log.error("error: " + e.getMessage());
      return Mono.empty();
});
```